# how to replace NaN value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, imputation

I have a list of `NaN` values in my dataframe and I want to replace NaN values with an empty string.

What I've tried so far, which isn't working:

```
df_conbid_N_1 = pd.read_csv("test-2019.csv",dtype=str, sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
df_conbid_N_1['Excep_Test'] = df_conbid_N_1['Excep_Test'].replace("NaN","")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `fillna` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)):
An example -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'no': [1, 2, 3],
                    'Col1':['State','City','Town'],
                  'Col2':['abc', np.NaN, 'defg'],
                  'Col3':['Madhya Pradesh', 'VBI', 'KJI']})

df

   no   Col1    Col2    Col3
0   1   State   abc Madhya Pradesh
1   2   City    NaN VBI
2   3   Town    defg    KJI

df.Col2.fillna('', inplace=True)
df

    no  Col1    Col2    Col3
0   1   State   abc     Madhya Pradesh
1   2   City            VBI
2   3   Town    defg    KJI
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple! you can do this way

```
df_conbid_N_1 = pd.read_csv("test-2019.csv",dtype=str, sep=';',encoding='utf-8').fillna("")
```

Answer (score 0):

We have pandas' [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill missing values.

---

Let's go through some uses cases with a sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['John', np.nan, 'Anne'], 'col2':[np.nan, 3, 4]})

   col1  col2
0  John   NaN
1   NaN   3.0
2  Anne   4.0
```

As mentioned in the docs, `fillna` accepts the following as fill `values`:

> values: scalar, dict, Series, or DataFrame

So we can replace with a **constant value**, such as an empty string with:

```
df.fillna('')

   col1 col2
0  John     
1          3
2  Anne    4
1
```

You can also replace with a **dictionary** mapping `column_name:replace_value`:

```
df.fillna({'col1':'Alex', 'col2':2})

   col1  col2
0  John   2.0
1  Alex   3.0
2  Anne   4.0
```

Or you can also replace with another **`pd.Series`** or **`pd.DataFrame`**:

```
df_other = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['John', 'Franc', 'Anne'], 'col2':[5, 3, 4]})

df.fillna(df_other)

    col1  col2
0   John   5.0
1  Franc   3.0
2   Anne   4.0
```

This is very useful since it allows you to fill missing values on the dataframes' columns using some extracted statistic from the columns, such as the `mean` or `mode`. Say we have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(np.r_[np.nan, np.arange(3)], (3,5)))
print(df)

     0    1    2    3    4
0  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0
1  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
```

Then we can easilty do:

```
df.fillna(df.mean())

     0    1    2    3    4
0  1.0  1.5  0.0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.5  1.5
```